# Virtualenvwrapper .hook: Permission Denied

Tags: python, wrapper, virtualenv, dollar-sign

I've used `virtualenvwrapper` previously, but I'm having problems running it on a new computer. My `.bashrc` file is updated per the instructions:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$DEV_HOME/projects
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

But when `source` is run, I get the following:

```
bash: /25009.hook: Permission denied
bash: /25009.hook: No such file or directory
```

[This previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/in-bash) leads me to believe the filename is being recycled and locked because `virtualenvwrapper.sh` uses `$$`. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try storing your virtualenvs directory somewhere you are guaranteed not to have any permissions errors (and maybe even try using the absolute path). Also, are you sure you created the 'projects' directory manually?

For reference, my bashrc file looks something like this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=/srv/.virtualenvs/
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE = WORKON_HOME
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And my .virtualenvs directory is chmodded to 755.