# what does `$$` represent in ps command?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does $$ mean in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell)

```
$ ./cruncher & ./cruncher & ./cruncher &
$ ps -C cruncher -p $$ -o pid,state,cmd
PID S CMD
2588 S bash
2657 R /bin/sh ./cruncher
2658 R /bin/sh ./cruncher
2659 R /bin/sh ./cruncher

-C cmdlist      Select by command name.
                       This selects the processes whose executable name is
                       given in cmdlist.

-p pidlist      Select by PID.
                       This selects the processes whose process ID numbers
                       appear in pidlist.
```

**Question**> What is the meaning of `$$`?

Comment: [$$ refers to the PID of the bash instance running the script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/78528/391104)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the `ps` command, `$$` is substituted by the shell with **its process ID**.

Answer (score 1):

It's a built-in shell variable which holds the `PID` process ID.