# what does $$ mean in linux script?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does $$ mean in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell)
>   [What are the Special Dollarsign Variables (Possibly bash Only)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollarsign-variables-possibly-bash-only)

I am new to linux environment. I am  dealing with a particular  script that has a command like this

```
ps -p $$
```

-p should follow a process id but I don't understand what $$ means. \
Could some linux gurus shed light on it ? isit a var where is it coming frome etc.,,

Thanks

Comment: The special `$`-based variables are described in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollarsign-variables-possibly-bash-only - `$$` itself means this process' PID.

Comment: Is it a varibale ? when I do env I don't see it ...

Comment: `env` displays the environment.  variables are not the same as environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special `$$` variable evaluates to the current process' PID (process ID) -- it is an integer number; it's not listed by `env` as it's *not* an environment variable. It's a special built-in variable provided by BASH.