# Bash script to kill a process via PID

Tags: linux, bash

I am making a basic bash script. I am trying to get a PID value and store it in a variable. I got my script setup like this:

```
getPID = pgrep -f app.jar
kill -9 $getPID
```

And then, I realized that I was only printing `pgrep -f app.jar` onto the terminal. So I tried:

```
getPID = $(pgrep -f app.jar)
kill -9 $getPid
```

And still no luck, is there a way to get `pgrep` value and store it in the variable?
I came across multiple questions. And still no luck. I also tried this, not too sure what does `$$` does.

```
pgrep -f app.jar
getPid = $$
kill $getPid
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 terminal.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ will catch your problem here. (You can't have spaces around `=` in an assignment).

Comment: ... isn't the best idea using `SIGKILL` e.g. the `-9`. It really kills the process immediatelly and the program couldn't handle the correct termination... Just use `kill` without any number - the default is `-15` e.g. `SIGTERM`, and only if absolutely needed use the `-9`.

Comment: Thanks jm666, yeah one of my colleagues was telling me to use ```SIGTERM``` instead of `SIGKILL`. Unless the program is not really closing properly, but thanks for the advice..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$$` stands for the PID of the current shell, not the output of the previous command.

The correct way of capturing the output of `pgrep` into a variable is:

```
getPid=$(pgrep -f app.jar)  # note: no spaces around =
kill $getPid
```

To make it more resilient to `pgrep` finding no matching processes, do:

```
getPid=$(pgrep -f app.jar)
[[ $getPid ]] && kill $gitPid
```

Or you can use `pkill` to do this in one shot:

```
pkill -f app.jar
```

---

See also:

- [What does $$ mean in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell)
- [How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)